# Bootstrap 4 выбор табов Select

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Доброе время суток господа, вопрос вроде и простой а вроде и сложный, необходимо выбирать стандартные bootstrap 4 табы выпадающим списком select, а не в ссылками...

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Из вопроса несколько не ясно, показываются ли у вас заголовки табов. Если они есть, то все довольно просто.

```js
$("select").change(function(){
   var id = $(this).val();   
   $("a[href='" + id + "']").tab('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 


<div class="m-3">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" >home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" >profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" >contact</div>
  </div>
</div>

<select class="m-4 form-control w-25">
   <option value="#nav-home">home</option>
   <option value="#nav-profile">profile</option>
   <option value="#nav-contact">contact</option>
</select>
```

Если заголовки не показываются, то в целом задача сводится к переключению классов `.show .active`, хотя, вероятно в этом случае не будут срабатывать события `show.bs.tab` и т.п., да и в целом тут bs не нужен, обычное скрытие/отображение блоков.

```js
$("select").change(function(){
   var id = $(this).val();
   $(id).addClass('show active')
        .siblings() 
            .removeClass('show active');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<div class="tab-content m-3" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" >home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" >profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" >contact</div>
</div>

    <select class="m-4 form-control w-25">
       <option value="#nav-home">home</option>
       <option value="#nav-profile">profile</option>
       <option value="#nav-contact">contact</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Заголовки не показываются

Comment: @ДенисЛинник дополнил примером